# How to disable/assert/override inferred types when importing JSON in typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am using the "resolveJsonModule" feature in typescript 2.9 in order to import a json file. Let's say the json file looks like this:

```
{
  "Nabokov": {
    "Pale Fire": {
      "Pages": "200",
      "Edition": "Paperback",

    },
    "Pnin": {
      "Pages": "150",
      "Edition": "Hardcover"
    },
    "Lolita": {
      "Pages": "150",
      "Edition": "Paperback",
      "Year": "1955"
    }
  },
  "Joyce": {
    "Ulysses": {
      "Pages": "800",
      "Language": "English"
    },
    "Finnegan's Wake": {
      "Pages": "1200",
      "Language": "Gibberish"
    }
  }
}
```

and i am importing it by:

import catalog from '../resources/catalog.json'

Okay, so when this gets imported, typescript will automatically define types for this. This becomes problematic for me when I am trying to write, for example, a function that can return the info for a author/book.

I want to just do

```
function getBook(author: string, title: string) {
  return catalog[author][title]
}
```

I get a "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' ..."  So it wants me to define author as "Nabokov" | "Joyce" but
since the JSON file will be forever expanding, and I don't know what's going to be in it at any time, I want to "genericize" the type for the imported object so that it's just something like [key: string].

Comment: Declare it as `keyof typeof catalog`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
type C = typeof catalog;
function getBook<T extends keyof C>(author: T, title: keyof C[T]) {
    return catalog[author][title]
}

getBook("Nabokov", "Lolita"); // OK
getBook("Joyce", "Lolita"); // Not OK
```

Here is a [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#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) to demonstrate.

#### Update

Based on your use case, you shouldn't restrict the types of the parameters, and you should just do this:

```
function getBook(author: string, title: string) {
    try {
        return (catalog as any)[author][title]
    } catch(e) {
        // do error handling here
    }
}
```

#### Update 2

The method mentioned above is more or less bypassing TypeScript. If one really want to ensure type-safety, here's the genuine TypeScript approach to do the same thing.

```
type B = {
    Pages: string;
    Edition?: string;
    Year?: string;
    Language?: string;
};
type C = {
    [index: string]: {
        [index:string]: B
    }
};

function getBook(author: string, title: string): B | undefined {
    const cat: C = catalog;
    if(author in cat && title in cat[author]) {
        return cat[author][title];
    } else {
        // do error handling here
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

See this [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBCAhjRAbMBzOBeOBvYASACIA5RAIzAGswA3YgLnyJIAU0BTOAMQEsATpyYtCY4hwycoI4gCYADAuIAaViQCiAEz4w+kWRwAOnARUQhqq4KwC+a8Wwh8IIgmPaIpM5sQCMAKzKDuLauvquvgASiAJa4HSmxHYhxAAyYKi6iG7qEl7SsoHBeWF6Br7GpuaW1h7EAJqcsUUAnAEByWK2RPZExABSYACeIMLM7iQAqqjDUFCFE3mSi3DEABxKdeJpiBAYAK4Fshr7WVAAFl2EfeL8EBCcGHsA5FBwAOqI1OOijgU+NZ+RQleq7fZHKSyADifAoFFMfEu1x6N2AtgA3DYYMMTHAAEI4FhwElwFZQZiwAQuDBY0lwMoRAD8lJg1P2dNJTViLLgVJpnJJ4MOBV5-I56KxOLxAGEiQR6QBtFxaTgAD1Z7IwAF0lvSlSr1YxxTrmPjgPSepibAAzA4QEDlCBwKQwfFgGgACkQBxgFzAAk1NJUcD0MFQnCD+wAlGa4AAfOD21U2lycLTE0ngaDwJAwZhy3B5tCYQVwPg272+-0CcvOvNwABkjdDugjdYQyEVPr9Ae10cz+rgQhgBwE9a7PZr2sVYYj2rLtjgnFQCz+AHp13AtGBlwIBAG4Bc9losvsj6ZOKwR2PncnOKnHlosWiekA).

Comment: Awesome, so that works to give me all the types in the catalog. But let's say I do not know for certain the inputs I will get for author and title, like they are a string input (console or web or whatever). So all I know is that a user will input a string which may or may not be a book or author in the catalog. I want to still be able to use the function, and just catch the error (or return not found). But now, it won't let me use: getBook(author, title) since it wants to enforce that the author and title types exist in the catalog. So basically I want to make the catalog's type more generic.

Comment: The (____ as any) is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for your patience with me and I apologize my question wasn't clearer from the get-go.

Comment: @kindofgreat Or it could be just me getting too obsessed with TypeScript generics and not paying enough attention to your question 

Comment: `as any` is a terrible solution: why do you use typescript if you don't type your data.

Comment: @zerkms It's not terrible at all for OP's particular use case, as he needs to check unpredictable keys(feel free to suggest any alternative with shorter TypeScript codes); and there could be a thousand other reasons why he uses TypeScript for his project.

Comment: "any alternative with shorter TypeScript codes" --- typescript purpose is not to make code shorter, but type safe. You totally can do it safer even with unknown keys.

Comment: @zerkms Of course I can by adding index signature to `catalog`, but you fail to consider the side-effect that it would then allow arbitrary access to the `catalog` object, and you don't know if that's what the OP wants. If one needs to both restrict arbitrary access and check for arbitrary keys, `as any` is the only option; correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: "that it would then allow arbitrary access" --- you're already doing that. `type C2 = {[index: string]: { [index:string]: { Pages: string; Edition?: string; Year?: string; Language?: string;  } }};` just assign to this type and you can make type-safe lookup. Or the most nested can also be a dictionary from `string` to `string`. Nevertheless - that code would be type safe, like the whole purpose of typescript.

Comment: @zerkms Of course I'm doing that, because that what the OP wants under that context! But he didn't mean that out of that particular context, arbitrary access is also allowed. What you're doing will allow arbitrary access in any context.

Comment: @Mu-Tsun Tsai: "What you're doing will allow arbitrary access in any context" --- nope, only within that function: `const catalog2: C2 = catalog;` Then you can make a type-safe and runtime-safe check `if (author in catalog2)` etc

Comment: @zerkms Fair enough, that might be a better method, I admit. Why don't you go ahead and submit a new answer?

Comment: @Mu-TsunTsai I already upvoted you long ago, and your answer is checked :-) If you add that another alternative it would teach the community how to write safer TS :-) no one ever checks the second popular answer :-D

Comment: @zerkms Fine~~~